# exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed] when trying full text search

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I tried to implement a full text search in spring data elasticsearch, but when a request is sent this exception is raised "Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]"

```java
MultiMatchQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(searchTerm)
                .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.CROSS_FIELDS)
                .operator(Operator.AND)
                .field("firstName")
                .field("lastName")
                .field("activeDirectoryUsername")
                .field("employeeNumber")
                .field("personalEmail")
                .field("corporateEmail")
                .field("project");

        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
                .postFilter(queryBuilder);

        SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest("employee");
        request.source(searchSourceBuilder);

        SearchResponse response = client.search(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

the exception is raised in the last line.

Comment: what is the motive for use postFilter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the employeeNumber field, I don't know if it because it a long or because, it was a Long when the index was created and I changed it to a String and a mismatch occured between the index and my spring document but it worked find after I deleted the index and recreated it